# Need to add a "generated value" to the results in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a query

```
[ { "$match" : { "vm_id" : "218276"}},{ "$group" : { "_id" : { "$dayOfMonth" : "$ts"} , "public_tx_total" : { "$sum" : "$interface_public_tx_bytes"} , "public_rx_total" : { "$sum" : "$interface_public_rx_bytes"} , "private_tx_total" : { "$sum" : "$interface_private_tx_bytes"} , "private_rx_total" : { "$sum" : "$interface_private_rx_bytes"} , "count" : { "$sum" : 1}}},{ "$sort" : { "_id" : 1}} ]
```

where I want to add a key that takes $ts and pulls the year out of and add it to the results

```
year: {$year: "$ts"}
```

I 'm not sure where to place the snippet without causing an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by adding the following command into the group query.

```
"year" : {$first : { $year:"$ts"}}
```

Your query will look like :

```
[
  {"$match":{"vm_id":"218276"}},
  {"$group":{"_id":{"$dayOfMonth":"$ts"}, 
    "year":{$first:{$year:"$ts"}}, 
    "public_tx_total":{"$sum":"$interface_public_tx_bytes"}, 
    "public_rx_total":{"$sum":"$interface_public_rx_bytes"}, 
    "private_tx_total":{"$sum":"$interface_private_tx_bytes"}, 
    "private_rx_total":{"$sum":"$interface_private_rx_bytes"}, 
    "count":{"$sum":1}}},
  {"$sort":{"_id":1}}
]
```

Comment: @Clutch: Unless your values are all in the same year, `$first` may not return what you expect. It will be the `$year` extracted from the first `$ts` value seen.  Without specifying a `$sort` order before the grouping, the value of first will not be predictable.  The answer from `zero323` suggesting grouping with a compound `_id` is a better approach if you want a meaningful `year` value.